# xpath select item by property value one of enum

Tags: xml, xpath

Tell me please, can i select item by xpath like this `//Item[@id='1|2|3']` and how?

here is examle of xml:

```
<Items>   
 <Item id='1'/>
 <Item id='3'/>
 <Item id='5'/>
 <Item id='7'/>
<Items/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath-2.0 or above, you can use

```
//Item[@id=(1,2,3)]
```

but in XPath-1.0 you have to use

```
//Item[@id=1 or @id=2 or @id=3]
```